# environment variable PATH changes inside script command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, environment-variables

I usually tend to keep a log of certain sessions using the useful `script` command. But, I observed that behaviour seems to change upon using it. To be precise,

before using `script`, the location of python is given as follows

```
$ which python
/home/abhishek/Softwares/anaconda3/bin/python
```

while upon applying `script`, it changes to

```
$ which python
/home/abhishek/Softwares/miniconda2/bin/python
```

I suspected this was due to different order of Python home directories being added to env variable, `PATH` which I confirmed as below

*before* `script`

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/abhishek/Softwares/anaconda3/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/anaconda3/condabin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/miniconda2/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/wkhtmltox/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/asymptote-2.41/installation_dir/bin:/home/abhishek/bin:/home/abhishek/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/abhishek/.dotnet/tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

*after* `script`

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/abhishek/Softwares/miniconda2/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/wkhtmltox/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/anaconda3/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/anaconda3/condabin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/miniconda2/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/wkhtmltox/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/abhishek/Softwares/asymptote-2.41/installation_dir/bin:/home/abhishek/bin:/home/abhishek/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/abhishek/.dotnet/tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

I tried understanding how `$PATH` is set inside `script` by looking at [where $PATH is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676849/where-is-path-variable-set-in-ubuntu) in general. From that, I checked the contents of `/etc/environment` (which seemed most relevant) as

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Not sure of the mechanism of how variable set from above though.

Hence, to ensure intended python installation is chosen, I would like to know how `$PATH` is reset inside `script`

Comment: What interactive shell are you in before you execute the `script` command? What is the value of `$SHELL` in that environment? `script` forks a new shell (using `$SHELL` if set), so it's likely the initialization file(s) for `$SHELL` that are changing your `PATH`

Comment: @steeldriver Both before and after `script` , the output for `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/bash` So, I guess the same shell being used

Comment: `echo $0` would be more definitive for the "before" shell. There could still be differences e.g. the original may be a login shell (reading .profile or .bash_profile) and the forked shell a non-login interactive shell (reading .bashrc).